# (First order logic) Proof with resolution rule

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Hi I have following set of clauses:

$$\forall x \exists y (R(x,y))$$
$$\forall x \forall y (R(x,y) \to R(y,x))$$
$$\forall x \forall y \forall z ((R(x,y) \land R(x,z)) \to R(y,z))$$

I need to prove (using resolution rule) that:
$$\forall x R(x,x)$$

I know already that it is provable by doing an informal proof. 
Since $\forall x \exists y (R(x,y))$ we can conclude that there is y for each x such that $R(x,y)$. By $\forall x \forall y (R(x,y) \to R(y,x))$ we see that there is also $R(y,x)$. Finally by $\forall x \forall y \forall z ((R(x,y) \land R(x,z)) \to R(y,z))$ we can conclude that $(R(y,x) \land R(y,x)) \to R(x,x)$ since $(x,y,z)$ can be arbitrarily chosen.

My question is how to transform above formulas by using resolution rule in order to get $\emptyset$. 
So by negating entire formula we recive following set of clauses that must by further handled:

Using skolemization on first one we get:
$$R(x,f(x))$$
Second:
$$\neg R(x,y) \lor R(y,x)$$
Third:
$$\neg R(x,y) \lor \neg R(x,z) \lor R(y,z)$$
Finally we have negated conclusion ($a$ is constant):
$$\neg R(a,a)$$

How to manipulate above clauses in order to prove entire formula and achieve $\emptyset$?

I'll appreciate any answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need [Unification](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4700/2011fa/lectures/16_FirstOrderLogic.pdf).

We have:

> $R(x,f(x))$
>
> $\lnot R(v,w) \lor R(w,v)$
>
> $\lnot R(k,j) \lor \lnot R(k,h) \lor R(j,h)$

and the negation of the conclusion:

> > $\lnot R(a,a).$

First substitition: $a ↦ v$, $a ↦ j$, $a ↦ h$ and $k ↦ w$ to get:

> $R(x,f(x))$
>
> $\lnot R(a,k) \lor R(k,a)$
>
> $\lnot R(k,a) \lor \lnot R(k,a) \lor R(a,a)$
>
> $\lnot R(a,a).$

Applying the [Resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_rule) to 2nd and 3rd we get:

> $R(x,f(x))$
>
> $\lnot R(a,k) \lor R(a,a)$
>
> $\lnot R(a,a).$

Now we need the substitution: $f(x) ↦ k$ and $a ↦ x$ to get:

> $R(a,f(a))$
>
> $\lnot R(a,f(a)) \lor R(a,a)$
>
> $\lnot R(a,a).$

With resolution on 1st and 2nd:

> $R(a,a)$
>
> $\lnot R(a,a)$

and it is done.